# Sockets in Linux - serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

Tags: linux, sockets

I am doing Socket Programming in Linux. Had a question.
How is it possible for us to allow specific IP addresses to connect to our **server**.

For instance:

- Allow 10.0.0.1
- Deny 10.0.0.1

I am specifically talking about this Line of Code where we fill **INADDR_ANY** to our **sockaddr_in struct**

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Rest of the Code just for Reference:

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;


serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Here's my question!!
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty, but isn't `serv_addr` the server socket?  As in, it's the TCP socket that you use to listen?  In the line you reference, that's just setting the IP address of the interface to listen on, not what's connecting.

Comment: @austin Actually 'serv_addr' is the struct that contains the information of the server. The Port No, IPs allowed, TCP/IP v4/v6 etc.
And yes, It is allowing all the connections to be accepted. What I want is to limit that to specific IPs. Btw, Listening and Accepting is done after this step.

Comment: Austin's absolutely right: if serv_addr is used to bind the listening socket, you can't put a peer's IP address in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a firewall. On linux, you set it up using `iptables(8)`.

If you want to do it in your application, it's not possible to listen selectively based on the peer's address (you can only listen selectively based on your address, and if you're on linux with the "weak-end system model" you have to check you understand what that means!---listening on a specific address probably doesn't quite do what you expect and isn't a secure way to discard packets from untrusted interfaces.).

Instead, listen on INADDR_ANY, then call `getpeername(2)` on the accepted fd, validate it, and close the connection if it doesn't match your application's filter.

Comment: That is something I have never tried. Looks workable and easy too. But still for knowledge purposes, how is actually selected IPs allowed in my code's approach.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're asking. If you want a way to bind the socket only to accept connections from specific IP addresses, you can't. That's just not possible with the sockets API. You have to listen for all connections, then close the ones you don't want, as I describe in the last paragraph. Your code's approach sounds like it can't work.

Comment: Just FYI, on most platforms, including Linux, it is not possible to selectively `accept()` clients based on their IPs. However, it is possible on Windows, by using `WSAAccept()` instead of `accept()`. `WSAAccept()` allows app code to analyze and decide whether to accept or reject a pending client that is in the backlog queue.